# sonar cloud plugin fails on missing class

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarcloud

I have an public project on github. i try to attach sonarcloud to it:

```
./mvnw -X clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent package sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io -Dsonar.organization=xxxx-github -Dsonar.login=yyyy
```

project is built, tests passes and then `sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar` executes:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar (default-cli) on project xxx: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar failed: A required class was missing while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar: org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/IssueListener

and at the end of the stacktrace:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.IssueListener

what's missing? how to fix that?

- mvn wrapper with mvn version: apache-maven-3.5.2
- java 8
- ubuntu 14.04

Comment: What is the version of SonarQube?

Comment: You should get in touch with the SonarCloud team to help you : https://about.sonarcloud.io/contact/

Comment: @JeroenHeier it's sonar **cloud**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

completing @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam advice:

changing `sonar:sonar` to `org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar` solved the problem

so now it is:

```
./mvnw -X clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent package org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io -Dsonar.organization=xxxx-github -Dsonar.login=yyyy
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a more recent version of the scanner for Maven. Last released version is 3.3.0.603.